# How to get an SVG to push right in div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, frontend

I'm trying to get a svg to align to the end of the div it's in. The div is displaying in flex and I attached the "align-self: flex-end" to the a tag the svg is in. I've also tried block, float-right. And a few other things. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<div class="d-flex">
  <a class="text-success" href="#"><h4 class="font-weight-bold mr-5">CRM Partners</h4></a>
  <a href="#" class="text-success svg-end"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 256 512" class="angle-right text-success" style="min-width: 13px;"><path d="M187.8 264.5L41 412.5c-4.7 4.7-12.3 4.7-17 0L4.2 392.7c-4.7-4.7-4.7-12.3 0-17L122.7 256 4.2 136.3c-4.7-4.7-4.7-12.3 0-17L24 99.5c4.7-4.7 12.3-4.7 17 0l146.8 148c4.7 4.7 4.7 12.3 0 17z"/></svg></a>
</div>
```

```
.svg-end {
    align-self: flex-end;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok...I swear I tried this before. But putting mr-auto on the first div did the trick.

```
<div class="d-flex">
  <a class="text-success mr-auto" href="#"><h4 class="font-weight-bold">Collaboration Unified Communications</h4></a>
  <a href="#" class="text-success"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 256 512" class="angle-right text-success" style="min-width: 13px;"><path d="M187.8 264.5L41 412.5c-4.7 4.7-12.3 4.7-17 0L4.2 392.7c-4.7-4.7-4.7-12.3 0-17L122.7 256 4.2 136.3c-4.7-4.7-4.7-12.3 0-17L24 99.5c4.7-4.7 12.3-4.7 17 0l146.8 148c4.7 4.7 4.7 12.3 0 17z"/></svg></a>
</div>
```